# How to remove http header from http response fields Liferay-Portal, Server?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, liferay, portlet

Working with liferay it's always says about portal in response:

```
Liferay-Portal:Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.1.0 CE (Paton / Build 6100 / January 6, 2012)
Server:GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1
```

how can I delete these information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to delete headers added to the `HttpServletResponse` object. The only way to handle this problem is by `Wrapping the HttpServletResponse` object using `Filter` and eat the headers  your want to ignore.

Here is the Sample code to use,

```
public class EatHeadersFilters implements Filter
{
   private List<String> headers;
   public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException
   {
      String headersString = filterConfig.getInitParameter("headers");
      String[] strings = headersString.split(",");
      headers = Arrays.asList(strings);
   }

   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
         FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException
   {
       filterChain.doFilter(request, 
           new HttpServletResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response){
              public void addHeader(String headerName, String headerValue)
              {
                  if(!headers.contains(headerName)){
                   super.addHeader(headerName, headerValue);
                  } else {
                   //eat the header
                  }
              }
         });
    }

   public void destroy()
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: what if I want to delete from all portal?

Comment: Edited my answer, please check.

Comment: I'm trying to remove filter-class from the Response Header, how can I implement this?

Answer (score 2):

Ramesh is correct, but this is pure Servlet implementation. Please check the interface `com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.WrapHttpServletResponseFilter`. It is provided by the same purpose. It will work in the Portlet Context.

Comment: Can I do it using portal configuration? Without programming?

Comment: you can, but limited feature. please have a look at http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/http-header-response

Comment: Thank you for answer, can you describe how i can use my new created class implementing filter, for catch all responses?

Comment: Hi, By looking at the code, you have to just put the filter and filter mapping in the web.xml, the InvokerFilterChain class will identify this and produce the wrapped response.

Answer (score 2):

You may use following key in portal-ext.properties to display only App name and Edition (e.g. Community)

```
http.header.version.verbosity=partial
```

That should not display specific version.

Original resource was found at http://arunkumarsrm.blogspot.com/2012/11/liferay-611-ga2-application-security.html

Also you may check further on following tickets to get acquainted with provided patch (I have not tried that)

http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-2748

http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-9011

**UPD: ** Actually you may completely disable server info with following options:

```
# portal-ext.properties:
http.header.version.verbosity=Liferay Portal Community Edition
```

and following config in /tomcat-7.0.27/conf/server.xml

```
<Connector
  URIEncoding="UTF-8"
  connectionTimeout="20000"
  port="8080"
  protocol="HTTP/1.1"
  redirectPort="8443"
  server="My Server!"
 />
```

Resource: http://tech-annex.blogspot.com/2013/01/hidding-server-signaturebanner.html